# Run applet java application from Linux terminal which depends on other jar files

Tags: java, linux, terminal, applet

I am new to Java.

I would like to run an applet from the command line.

I have the next scenario:

```
test/lib/dependency_1.jar
test/lib/dependency_2.jar
test/src/module1/HelloWorld.java  // Applet application
```

I achieve compilation with

```
-cp "../../lib/dependency_1:../../lib/dependency_2"
```

from inside the 'module1' folder.

Now that I think everything will run using simply the "java" interpreter from the command line, I get the complain:

```
Usage: PApplet <appletname>
For additional options, see the Javadoc for PApplet
```

I continue my search and I get into appletview. I create the next html file at the 'test/src' directory:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> Launches the 'HelloWorld' applet: HelloWorld.class! </p>  
        <applet 
            code="module1/HelloWorld.class"   
            archive="../lib/dependency_1.jar: \
                     ../lib/dependency_2.jar"
            height=700 
            width=800>
        No Java?!
        </applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

Running "appletviewer HelloWorld.html" - Answer: "Applet not initialized"

It looks like it is not able to find the dependencies.

Could somebody tell me how to include those dependencies inside the html file? Or point me out where I am wrong?

Thanks in advance.

-------------------------------- NEW EDIT ------------------------------

This is how it looks like right now the directory tree:

```
├── lib
│   ├── dependency_1.jar
│   └── dependency_2.jar
└── src
|   ├── module1
|   │   ├── dependency_1.jar     // copied into module1/
|   │   ├── HelloWorld.class
|   │   ├── HelloWorld.html
|   │   ├── HelloWorld.java
|   │   └── dependency_2.jar     // copied into module1/
```

And the HelloWorld.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> Applet HelloWorld.class! </p>  
        <applet code="module1.HelloWorld"
                archive="./depencency_1.jar:./dependency_2.jar"
                height=700 width=800>
        No Java?!
        </applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

Execution of: appletwiewer module1/HelloWorld.html

Result: Applet not initialized

At command line:

```
load: class module1.HelloWorld not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: module1.HelloWorld
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(AppletClassLoader.java:219)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(AppletClassLoader.java:152)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(AppletClassLoader.java:633)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:795)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:724)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:380)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: `../lib/dependency_1.jar` Does it work if the dependency jars are in the same directory as the class file? Is the `lib` directory part of a web app.?

Comment: Hello Andrew, I have placed the dependencies in the same directory and modified the HelloWorld.html ( archive="./dependency_1:./dependency_2")

Executing from the same dir: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ..HelloWorld.class"

Comment: Show the structure of the server, indicating the paths to the HTML, the class file and the Jars. Show the updated HTML as an [edit] to the question. Is `HelloWorld`in a package? If so, what is the package name?

Comment: @AndrewThompson, please find after the line "NEW EDIT" the info you asked for.
HelloWorld is in a package called module1. In this package it is only the class HelloWorld.

Comment: Given the class is in a package, the HTML needs to be in the parent directory. That listing looks suspiciously like the structure an IDE might use. Why is there a `src` directory on the server?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention.. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: That is correct @AndrewThompson, both assumptions. First, moving the html file into the parent directory allowed me to have a "Applet started" window (not showing anything inside for according Java security reasons). Second, it is a structure similar to the one Eclipse would establish because the course I am following uses Eclipse, but I am not big fan of IDE's so although I am just about starting with Java I truly want to keep with my terminal focus working way. Thanks for your help!!